# долгий ответ от стороннего API

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, api

Я получаю API от сторонних сервисов на PHP, процесс занимает некоторое время. Метод получения API вызывается AJAX запросом из вьюшки. Когда получение API достигнет сотни сервисов, я думаю скрипт будет долго думать. Подскажите как избежать большого времени выполнения получения API?

Comment: почему ты думаешь что скрипт будет долго думать?

Comment: и что такое "получение API достигнет сотни сервисов"

Comment: @Ипатьев, потому что ответ от одного содержит в себе большое количество информации, которая потом парсится в цикле. Потом полученный массив по ключам выводится на экран.

Comment: У сотни сервисов буду получать API, вот что такое :)

Comment: а зачем для обработки одного аякс-запроса опрашивать сто сервисов? типа хачю агригатор как aviasales? Ну так если ты посмотришь на то как он работает, то он как раз и "думает долго", других вариантов нет.

Comment: Ну да, вот допустим надо получить API цен билетов и направлений от 150 компаний. Как этот процесс сделать быстрым? И чтобы информация на моём сервисе обновлялась каждые 10 секунд у всех 150 сервисов

Comment: Ты читаешь вообще что тебе пишут? зайди на такой сервис раз в жизни и посмотри, мгновенно он тебе отображает, или нет. а за раз в 10 секунд тебя тупо забанят, и всё.

Comment: Обычно у таких сервисов есть система переопроса и кэширования данных, чтобы не спамить запросами, которые уже были сделаны и ещё актуальны.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала стоит убедиться, что ваш парсер работает оптимально. Если улучшить быстродействие скрипта не представляется возможном, советую использовать механизм очередей, подробней [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues)

Если коротко, механизм очередей позволит перевести обработку ответов в отдельный поток, который будет выполняться независимо от вашего сайта

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, Bad Idea опрашивать API прям из view сразу. В конце концов, это может привести к ситуации, когда API просто забанит IP адрес сервера (Такое часто бывает при использование ip geolocation сервисов). Я не могу, к сожалению, рассказать детальный план что и почему делать, так как не в курсе деталей, но я бы сделал так:

1. Поднял бы рядом с приложением Redis
2. Сделал бы cron задачу с опросом APIшки (период опросов тут либо исходя из требований задачи, либо Эмпирически) и сохранением данных в Redis
3. Метод котроллера нацелил бы на работу с Redis
4. Ну а фронт по AJAX стучит в метод контроллера

По итогу получаем: быстрее реакция на фронте, так как все необходимое под боком; не рискуем получить бан от сервера API
Минус - для получения данных в реальном режиме времени такой способ не подойдет. Да и мне кажется что REST API впринципе не про реалтайм изменения данных.